# Add Route names to array

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

Can I add the route to the array instead of using the `<a href>` as a string?

In this example, I am creating a link to `update-building` and add the `buildingId` as a parameter.

Is there a way to use the route name for 'update-building'?

```
 axios
      .get("https://localhost:44349/api/Building/List", headers)
      .then(response => {
        response.data.forEach(el => {

          this.dataset.push([
              el.city, 
              el.street, 
              el.number, 
              el.projectName, 
             `<a href='#/update-building/${el.buildingId}'>update</a>`, // use route name instead this
             ]);
        });
```

**my router file:**

```
 {
      path: '/update-building:buildingId',
      name: 'UpdateBuilding',
      component: UpdateBuilding,
      props: true,
      params: null,
      meta: {
        requiresAuth: true
      }
    },
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. Are you asking how to dynamically add routes to a vue-router instance? Or how to dynamically add strings to an array? Or how to dynamically add links to the document?

Comment: yes, I can see it's not clear. I rephrased.

Comment: you can use the resolve https://router.vuejs.org/api/#router-resolve method on the router instance: `this.$router.resolve({ name: 'UpdateBuilding', params: { buildingId: 123 }}).href`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

based on [nemesv](https://stackoverflow.com/users/872395/nemesv) is answer!

```
axios
      .get("https://localhost:44349/api/Building/List", headers)
      .then(response => {
        response.data.forEach(el => {

         var url = this.$router.resolve({ name: 'UpdateBuilding', params: { buildingId: el.buildingId }}).href
          this.dataset.push([
              el.city, 
              el.street, 
              el.number, 
              el.projectName, 
             `<a href='#/${url}/${el.buildingId}'>update</a>`, 
             ]);
    });
```